# ошибка при передаче данных между серверами

Tags: php, java

В универе задали задание сделать сайт с усложненной архитектурой, чтобы был сервер на PHP, который от клиента принимал запросы, потом отправлял их серверу на Java, который из БД доставал бы данные запрошенные и обратно PHP серверу отдавал. Я использую в Java *tomcat-embedded*, пока что работаем на локалхосте, PHP на порту 8000, а Java на 8080. Когда php пытается передать ответ на Java-сервер выходит ошибка 405:

> Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0) > POST /registration HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: application/json User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.4.1 curl/7.64.0 PHP/7.3.10 body: {"email":"muhaha@mail.ru","surname":"asf","name":"asdsdh","patronymic":"Pyrkovich","role":"student","password":"1234Q5678"} < HTTP/1.1 405 < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 < Content-Language: en < Content-Length: 1117 < Date: Sun, 10 Nov 2019 21:10:02 GMT < * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact Client error: `POST http://localhost:8080/registration` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` response

в чем может быть проблема? Запросы вроде все правильно написаны

Comment: Там всё черным по белому написано: `Method Not Allowed`. Java ждёт GET а вы ей кидаете POST.